# With GraphQL + Apollo Client, how to return a totalCount after mutating?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I have the following:

```
const typeDefs = `
type Request {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
  totalCount: Int
}

type Mutation {
  createRequest(email: String!): Request!
}
`;

export default typeDefs;
```

Right now totalCount is returning null. Using GraphQL, what is the right way to return the TotalCount as the mutation's response. Should totalCount be included somehow in the Request model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `totalCount` as a property of each `Request` object but `totalCount` represents the count of all `Request` objects.

The common practice to allow additional data in mutation response is to have it return a wrapper. For example:

```
type Mutation {
  createRequest(email: String!): CreateRequestResponse!
}

type CreateRequestResponse {
  request: Request!
  totalCount: Int!
}
```

The `CreateRequestResponse` is a wrapper object that can include any arbitrary attributes that the clients might need in the response. `totalCount` here is just an example; you can add any attribute there.

With that, the definition of `Request` type would be:

```
type Request {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
}
```

which is ideal because it only contains attributes of a specific Request.